# How to remove selected rows from DataGrid using PowerShell, WPF and XAML?

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, datagrid

**Hello,**

I am bit new to the **WPF** with **PowerShell**. My actual requirement is to delete selected rows from DataGrid while clicking on button. So, after clicking on button, selected rows should be gone from the DataGrid GUI.

This could be bit complex as I have used these technologies: **PowerShell, XAML, WPF and SCCM**(getting some data from it).

Here is the below **code** of **XAML** file.

```
<Grid>

<DataGrid Name="DGDriverPackage"
                Margin="10"
                MinWidth="200"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="480"
                CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                GridLinesVisibility="None"
                FontFamily="arial"
                FontSize="16"
                FrozenColumnCount="2"
                FontWeight="Regular"
                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                Cursor="Hand"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                Visibility="Hidden">
                    
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                        EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                        Header="Select" 
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Name="BtnDelete"
        Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Square}"
        Content="Delete"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Margin="10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="150"
        Height="30"
        Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the **code** of **PowerShell** where I set some **data** into **DataGrid**.

```
$DGV_PFM_OSD = $PFMOSDCleanupXaml.FindName("DGDriverPackage")
$SCCMApplications =  @()
foreach($App in $vUniqueApplicationofOldpfm){
       $SCCMApplications  += Get-CMApplication -Fast -Name $App | Select-Object LocalizedDisplayName, IsDeployed, DateCreated
}
$Fields = @('LocalizedDisplayName', "IsDeployed", "DateCreated")
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$Datatable.Columns.AddRange($Fields)
foreach ($SCCMApp in $SCCMApplications)
    {
         $Array = @()
         Foreach ($Field in $Fields)
         {
              $array += $SCCMApp.$Field
         }
         [void]$Datatable.Rows.Add($array)
}
$DGV_PFM_OSD.ItemsSource  = $Datatable.DefaultView
$Global:isDelete = 1
```

Here is the **code** of **PowerShell** which I have written to **delete rows** from **DataGrid** **Form.ps1** file

```
$BtnDelete = $PFMOSDCleanupXaml.FindName("BtnDelete")
$BtnDelete.add_Click({

    switch( $Global:isDelete )
    {

    # Deleting selected applications.
    1
    {
        foreach($SelectedApp in $DGV_PFM_OSD.SelectedItems){         
            $DGV_PFM_OSD.Items.RemoveAt($SelectedApp.Index)   //This line is not working.
            $DGV_PFM_OSD.Items.Remove($SelectedApp)           //This line is not working.
        }
    }
})
```

Below is my DataGrid looks like

[image]

Can someone suggest what I am missing or what I am doing wrong here.?

Comment: I don't believe editing the .Items of a DataTable is possible after setting its .ItemsSource. Try directly editing the source collection $Datatable.    Edit: Additionally, using an ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource will allow your table to automatically update when the ObservableCollection is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection that is being enumerated (e.g. by a foreach) as this would invalidate the current  `IEnumerator`.

The easiest way is to use the static `DataGrid.DeleteCommand` as this doesn't require any index handling etc.
Invoking the command using the `DataGrid` instance as the command's target will trigger the DataGrid to delete all selected items.

```
$BtnDelete.add_Click({

  switch($Global:isDelete)
  {

    # Deleting selected applications.
    1
    {
      [System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid]::DeleteCommand.Execute($null, $DGV_PFM_OSD)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: [System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid]::DeleteCommand.Execute($null, $DGV_PFM_OSD)
This code is not working at the moment, nothing happens.

Comment: Difficult to tell from here what exactly is not working. The key is to call the static `DataGrid.DeleteCommand` and pass in the current `DataGrid` instance as the command target (second parameter).